# jQuery:click function() ready doesn't work after the load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jQuery 3.2.1 if I build checkbox after the load function, the click function doesn't work when I click the checkbox.

If I build the checkbox before for testing, it works!

How can I code it so the click function works after dynamically building the checkbox in the load function?

```
<div id="idcheckbox">
</div>


$(window).on('load', function () {
      $("#idcheckbox").append("<div class='custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id=" + identifiant + " value=" + url + "><label class='custom-control-label' for=" + identifiant + ">" + url + "</label></div>");
});

$(document).ready(function () {

     $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {
                alert("0000");
            });

     $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function () {
                alert("1111");
            });

     //solution 
     $("#idcheckbox").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
                if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert("jQuery checked");
                } else {
                    alert("jQuery no checked");
                }
            });


});
```

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: Works just fine for me

Comment: you can clarify because the solution does not seem to work for me

Comment: alert is bad for testing, use `console.log` alert breaks flow. Your problem is order of operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding event on document.ready and then you are building control on window.load so it will not work because event is already bind with existing control. if you are making new control you need to add it after adding control to DOM.

```js
var identifiant = "dynamic",
    url = "www.google.com";
var counter = 1;
$(window).on('load', function() {
    dynamicControl();
});

function dynamicControl() {
    var id = identifiant + counter;
    $("#idcheckbox").append("<div class='custom-control custom-checkbox custom-control-inline'><input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id=" + id + " value=" + url + "><label class='custom-control-label' for=" + id + ">" + url + "</label></div>");
    $("#" + id).on('change', function() {
        alert('dynamic alert')
    });
    counter++;
}
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        alert("0000");
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function() {
        alert("1111");
    });
    $("#Dynamic").on('click', dynamicControl);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="idcheckbox">
</div>
<input type='button' id='Dynamic' value='Add new checkbox'/>
```

Comment: in load function i build multiple checkbox. 
in ready function i would like to click on it to launch a function

Comment: It's ok i understand :
            $("#idcheckbox").on("click", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
                if ($("input[type='checkbox']").is(':checked')) {
                    alert("jQuery checked");
                } else {
                    alert("jQuery no checked");
                }
            });